# Decrypting System.Security.SecureString

Tags: powershell

Working on a script based off this link https://pscustomobject.github.io/powershell/functions/PowerShell-SecureString-To-String/

I have created the credential, but when I am having trouble with the decrypt part where it is supposed to list the password in plain text. Instead of the password, I get a folder location returned to me.

```
$Credential

UserName                               Password
--------                               --------
backup_acct                   System.Security.SecureString

PS C:\Users\>System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Credential.Password))
E:\WindowsTasks\Secure\TempCreation
```

Any ideas on why that might be happening? It was working yesterday, but came back to do some more work on the script and this started happening.

Tried a different method of decrypting and got the same thing.

```
PS> $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
E:\WindowsTasks\Secure\TempCreation
```

Comment: Using `$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().password` just straight up spits back what it thinks the password is. Your code looks fine, I would question how you created the credentials.

Comment: We have a module that another co worker made that creates the credentials. That directory is where the credentials get created after we run the module. I wonder if something within that module is causing this to happen?